# Linq query syntax difference using SingleorDefault

Tags: c#, .net, linq, hibernate

This question may not be very relevant. It is more out of curiosity than anything else.

Is there any real advantage that Option1 has over Option2 in terms of speed?

```
Option1 

var avariable = session.Query<Someclass>()
                       .SingleOrDefault(x => x.something == someotherThing);

Option 2

var avariable = session.Query<Someclass>()
                       .Where(x => x.something == someotherThing)
                       .SingleOrDefault();
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: if this is being run through an NHibernate database access layer provider, then it might be up to it. I haven't used it directly, but if they both just translate to a single HQL query, then I doubt there's any performance difference.

Comment: When it comes to performance this is a must-read [Which is faster?](http://ericlippert.com/2012/12/17/performance-rant/)

Comment: Thanks for your answers. David, I have not really tried it. It just came through after a pass by resharper. Chris, I do also think that the HQL generated should be the same. Steve, you are right I should be benchmarking this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Option 1 is faster to type.

(They should both create the same sql therefore result in the same performance, option 1 is merely more concise)